# Can you have two values in a single rel attribute?

Tags: html, rel

The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document.

I am currently doing this:

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="author">Henry Wright</a>
```

I want to make sure the link is nofollow with reference to search engines. My question is do I do this by adding a second value to the rel attribute like this?

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="author nofollow">Henry Wright</a>
```

I'm not convinced this is the right approach so am reaching out for some help.

Answer (score 6):

Just read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel):

> The types of link indicated (the relationships) are given by the value of the `rel` attribute, which, if present, **must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens**. [The allowed keywords and their meanings](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) are defined in a later section.

Comment: Thanks to both yourself and to Guffa for answering

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple values in a `rel` attribute:

"The value of this attribute is a space-separated list of link types."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel

Comment: Thanks. I see now it is valid to have multiple attributes